# Getting a hundred of very similar compiler errors from 'cmath' and 'cstdlib'

Tags: c++, c, qt

I'm working on a C++ project which includes some C code as well from a third party. My build set-up is 'Desktop Qt 5.1.1 MSVC2012 64bit' which happens to be the default one when using Qt Creator on Windows, obviously.

When trying to compile the whole thing up, I get more than a hundred compiler errors. The weird thing is that all of them seem to be very closely related, as half of them come from the C Standard Library I assume (as it says 'cstdlib' on the errors) and the other half from the C Math Library (cmath). The following is an extract of the errors I'm getting,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\cstdlib:19: error: C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\cstdlib:19: error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\cstdlib:21: error: C2059: syntax error : ';'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\cmath:28: error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\cmath:28: error: C2059: syntax error : ';'
```

There's no need for me to copy more examples since all of them are quite like that.

Oddly enough, I only started getting this kind of errors when I started using QMake and the MSVC2012 compiler. Before starting to add the Qt frontend, I compiled the whole thing on the latest version of g++ (MinGW), with the C++11 flag enabled (note that this flag is also enabled in the Qt .pro file).

As I said, I wrapped a single C++ class around all the C modules I want to use. These C modules I'm talking about include the code to prevent C++ function decoration on their functions:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

Do you think this has to do with the compiler, with the code itself (maybe my C and my C++ are not correctly put together), the build or make configuration...?

Any hints or thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: _'As I said, I wrapped a single C++ class around all the C modules I want to use.'_ Show how you're doing this.

Comment: One common reason for this kind of problem is a syntax error (like a forgotten ";") right before the #include of the failing header file.

Comment: if you search by error number, MSDN may have some solutions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cyzw7b9.aspx

Comment: Could you paste your code up to (and including) the first problematic `#include`. Also, check that your code file has a C++ extyension and not a C extension.

Comment: Are you compiling C++ as C?

Comment: Besides Qt, did you use any 3rd party libraries in the project? It's an important information.

Comment: Does VS12 support all C++11-features? I don't think so.

Comment: If you solved it, you should add the solution as an answer, rather than updating the question. You can then even accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

`cstdlib` is *not* a C header, it's a C++ header. If you include it from a C file, you can expect anything and everything to happen.

From a C file, you **must** include `stdlib.h`. That's all. You don't have to change the extension of your source file to `.cpp` - since, after all, C++ is *not* C.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your "math" is used in your program.

However, at least some of the "math" related method of C programming is in "limits.h", such as INT_MIN.

Hence, I think you can try to include this header, and see if it works.